# Partition string in substrings of equal length and iterate through them

Tags: loops

To avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), I'll describe what I am looking for (the X) and the issue that I found while attempting X (the Y). To be clear: I'm not trying to troubleshoot Y, I'd be grateful if only X is solved.

## What I'm looking for

I want to define a macro that accepts a string as an argument and it displays a given number of characters (by calling an arbitrary macro) per page until the string is entirely traversed.

Here's an example: Let's consider the string `abcdefghijk`, 3 as the number of characters we want to display per page, and `\foo` the macro that we want to call for each character. The resulting document should look like.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\foo[1]{Hello #1}

\begin{document}
\foo{a} \foo{b} \foo{c}
\newpage
\foo{d} \foo{e} \foo{f}
\newpage
\foo{g} \foo{h} \foo{i}
\newpage
\foo{j} \foo{k}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

I came up with the following pseudocode:

```
1. While the original string is not empty:
  1.1. Create a substring from the first character to the third character.
  1.2. Remove the first three characters from the original string.
  1.3. For every character in the substring:
    1.3.1. Call \foo{character}
  1.4. Call \newpage
```

## My attempt

For step 1.2, the original string needs to be set to a substring of itself, so I tried setting `\mystring` to a substring to itself using the `\substring` from the `stringstrings` package, but I got the error `Use of \\substring doesn't match its definition.`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
% An arbitrary string
\def\mystring{abcdef}
% We obtain the length so that we can create a substring from the 4th
% character to the end of the string.
\StrLen{\mystring}[\mystringlen]
% When I try to display the string, I get the following error:
% ! Use of \\substring doesn't match its definition.
% \kernel@ifnextchar ...rved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
%                                                   #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
% l.14 \mystring
%
% ?
\def\mystring{\substring{\mystring}{4}{\mystringlen}}
\mystring
\end{document}
```

I feel there's a simpler way to implement the pseudocode that I explained above.

Comment: While what you say can be implemented, it would have a bad time complexity because of limitations in TeX's memory models. A better algorithm would be to iterate character by character, maintain a counter for the current index, and if the counter reaches 3, reset the counter to 0 and execute `\clearpage`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd split the text into a sequence, grapheme by grapheme, then map the sequence using the index, so after the specified number of items a `\newpage` command is issued. Each item is wrapped according to the template specified as the third argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=3cm,paperheight=4cm]{geometry} % just for smaller pictures

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\partitionstring}{mm+m}
 {% #1 = number of characters in the substrings
  % #2 = string
  % #3 = what to do to each item
  \rdrg_partition:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_rdrg_partition_items_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \rdrg_partition:nnn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_rdrg_partition_items_seq
  \text_map_inline:nn { #2 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_rdrg_partition_items_seq { ##1 } }
  \cs_set:Nn \__rdrg_partition_do:n { #3 }
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_rdrg_partition_items_seq
   {
    \__rdrg_partition_do:n { ##2 }
    \bool_lazy_or:nnT
     { \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn { ##1 } { #1 } == 0 } } % specified interval
     { \int_compare_p:n { ##1 == \seq_count:N \l_rdrg_partition_items_seq } } % end
     { \clearpage }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\partitionstring{3}{abćdefghìjk}{\fbox{#1}\par}

\raggedright Text on a new page

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want graphemes not bytes/characters (so e.g. retaining accents, handling 8-bit input properly):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \blockstring { O{3} m m }
  { \rdrg_block_string:nnN {#1} {#2} #3 }
\int_new:N \l__rdrg_block_int
\tl_new:N \l__rdrg_block_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \rdrg_block_string:nnN #1#2#3
  {
    \group_begin:
      \int_zero:N \l__rdrg_block_int
      \tl_clear:N \l__rdrg_block_tl
      \text_map_inline:nn {#2}
        {
          \int_incr:N \l__rdrg_block_int
          \tl_put_right:Nn \l__rdrg_block_tl {##1}
          \int_compare:nNnT \l__rdrg_block_int = {#1}
            {
              \int_zero:N \l__rdrg_block_int
              \exp_args:NV #3 \l__rdrg_block_tl
              \tl_clear:N \l__rdrg_block_tl
            }
        }
      \tl_if_empty:NF \l__rdrg_block_tl
        { \exp_args:NV #3 \l__rdrg_block_tl }
    \group_end:
  }
\begin{document}

\blockstring{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}\fbox

\end{document}
```

Comment: Behaviour if the input doesn't divide neatly into blocks was not specified: I assumed you'd just want to tidy up, but one could error or pad if required.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution attempt using TeX primitives:

```
\newcount\subnum 
\newcount\subnumA

\def\processdata#1{\subnum=#1 \subnumA=0 \expandafter\processdataA\data\end}

\def\processdataA#1{\ifx\end#1\newpage\else
   \foo{#1}\space
   \advance\subnumA by1
   \ifnum\subnumA<\subnum \else \newpage \subnumA=0 \fi
   \expandafter\processdataA \fi
}

\def\foo#1{Hello #1}
\def\data{abcdefghijk}

\processdata{3} % executes \foo{a} \foo{b} \foo{c} \newpage \foo{d} ... etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution attempt using ExplSyntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__rdrg_string_seq
\tl_new:N  \l__rdrg_string_left_tl
\str_new:N \l__rdrg_substring_str

\NewDocumentCommand \foo { m } { \__rdrg_foo:n {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__rdrg_foo:n #1
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nne \l__rdrg_string_seq { } { \tl_to_str:e {#1} }
    \int_do_until:nNnn { \seq_count:N \l__rdrg_string_seq } < { 3 }
      {
        \str_clear:N \l__rdrg_substring_str
        \prg_replicate:nn { 3 }
          {
            \seq_pop_left:NN \l__rdrg_string_seq \l__rdrg_string_left_tl
            \str_put_right:Ne \l__rdrg_substring_str
              { \l__rdrg_string_left_tl }
          }
        \str_map_function:NN \l__rdrg_substring_str \__rdrg_foo_fn:n
        \newpage
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__rdrg_foo_fn:n #1
  { 
    % example function
    { \color { red } This~ is~ the~ letter~ \textsf {#1} !!! }
    \par
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foo{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a token-cycle approach.  While this MWE assumes the input `\data` are all characters (no spaces, macros, or groups), the approach is easily modified to take those into account.

Here, I have defined `\triggeraction` as `\par\hrulefill\par` rather than `\newpage`, for easy viewing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
%
\newcommand\foo[1]{\fbox{#1}}
\newcommand\triggerindex{3}
\newcommand\triggeraction{\par\hrulefill\par}
%
\newcounter{myindex}
\Characterdirective{\addcytoks{%
  \foo{#1}\stepcounter{myindex}\ifnum\value{myindex}=\triggerindex\relax
    \triggeraction\setcounter{myindex}{0}\fi
}}
\newcommand\processfoo[1]{%
  \setcounter{myindex}{0}%
  \expandafter\tokencyclexpress#1\endtokencyclexpress
  \clearpage
}
\begin{document}
\def\data{abcdefghijk}
\processfoo{\data}
After text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `xstring`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=3cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{Hello #1\ }

\newcommand{\charbychar}[1]{%
   \StrSplit{#1}{1}{\firstchar}{\rest}%
   \foo{\firstchar}%
   \IfStrEq{\rest}{}{}{%
      \charbychar{\rest}%
   }
}
\newcommand{\splitcall}[2]{%
   \StrSplit{#1}{#2}{\firstn}{\restn}%
   \charbychar{\firstn}%
   \IfStrEq{\restn}{}{}{%
      \newpage%
      \splitcall{\restn}{#2}%
   }
}
\begin{document}
\splitcall{abcdefgh}{3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to use `\StrSplit` to split the original string into the first *n* characters and the rest, then process the first *n*, and if the rest is not empty call the command again (recursively) on the rest.

Processing the *n* characters works in the same way: split into the first character and the rest, call a macro `\foo` on the first character, if the rest isn't empty call the command recursively on the rest.

`\StrSplit` automatically takes care of uneven lengths, if the first part is not long enough (for example you ask to split on 3 characters but there are only 2) then the first part will be the complete string and the second part will be empty.